# Linking website pages together

Tags: html

I'm trying to learn how to link internal pages in a website, but my code doesn't work.  All the pages are saved in the same folder on localhost, and if I go directly to the address , the pages work. Here's my code. It's so simple, and I checked it 20 times as well. All the files are named correctly etc.

```
<html>
[...]
<body>
[...]
    <div id="footer">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <p>&copy;2014 MyMockupWebsite.com</p>
    </div><!--footer-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: try to add a slash `<a href="/home.php">Home</a>`

Comment: thank you just tried but still no go

Comment: i type in as below  and it goes to the right page http://localhost/demo/about.php

Comment: hi aldanux tried both still doesn't work , how very weird...

Comment: That don't work: `<a href="http://localhost/demo/about.php">Home</a>`?

Comment: yes, i just copied it from browser , too , not to miss anything, also tried "localhost/demo/about.php" route

Comment: and what's really bloody infuriating i just created 2 random new files in the  same folder and they link together just ace!

Comment: thanks for trying btw :) i think it's just one of those mysteries i might have to re-do, it will work and i'll never know what happened, maybe it's to do with the links being on the menu or something

Comment: What exactly happens when you click one of those links?  To which addresses do they take you?

Comment: hiya, they don't nothing happens except the tab colour changes which i set to change colour when clicked , whereas the two mock quick up pages link fine

Comment: Please post the `ls` or `dir` contents of that folder.

Comment: Hi Elliot , what are these two? 'ls' and 'dir'

Comment: well I sorted it not elegantly i suspect but it works. In this line 

 <?php include('header.php'); ?> I copied file 'header.php' exactly, saved it as header2.php , adjusted files and now it links

Comment: Do you have php installed on your server? Do you even have a server installed? Your computer won't execute php files if you don't have a server.

Comment: Hi Mario , I'm new to coding but I think it's all in place as everything else works and opens fine, I managed to sort this one as well by copying and renaming file (see above) no idea what happened though , which is a bit of a bummer

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<a href="./home.php">Home</a>
```

The ./ before the page name will cause the search to be in the same directory.

Comment: Hiya thank you I'd given it a go but it still didn't work , i ended up getting around it by by changing <?php include('header2.php'); ?> from original header.php without other changes and it work, so better than nothing although ideally I would have liked to know what actually happened.  I suspect that it was something to do with saving files but not adding "/demo/" and I tried both adding this and the full address and the new filename worked without anyway

Answer (score 0):

Add `<base href="/demo/">` to your head or /demo/ to your links. The problem is, that you haven't told the browser to look in your subfolder.

You can easily validate your links: just click on them, analyse the browser's addressbar and correct what's missing or extra in the address shown there.

Comment: Thanks Wedi, I'd given it a go but it still didn't work , i ended up getting around it by by changing <?php include('header2.php'); ?> from original header.php without other changes and it work, so better than nothing although ideally I would have liked to know what actually happened.  I suspect that it was something to do with saving files but not adding "/demo/" and I tried both adding this and the full address and the new filename worked without anyway

Comment: Very strange. Maybe you could update your question with the `include` call and your `header.php`?